# How can i call Java methodes from HTML

Tags: java, html, gwt

I'm using Google Maps, now if I click on the image it should call a java method.

```
infowindowOpts.setContent("<img scr="bla.png"> ");
```

Comment: Are you confusing Java and Javascript?

Comment: Not sure but you might use `infowindowOpts.getElement().appendChild()`.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795607/call-java-from-javascript-jsni might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call java method directly from html.

You can use JavaScript or Jquery for send ajax request to your servlet.
Servlet can call your java method and send JSON response.
again using Jquery(JavaScript) you can update your html code.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use `GWT JSNI`

**You can use [GWT JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to call Java method from JavaScript and vice-verse.**

**You have to just export you `Java` method to `JavaScript`.** Now in Java you have full control to do anything.

---

Find a sample code on [Calling GWT Java function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080099/calling-gwt-java-function-from-javascript)